# Recycler view in Android app is crashing at 9th entry

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have used recycler view in developing android app through Android Studio. I am using a button on click of which, the new entry will get added to the recyclerview. But, as soon as I enter the 9th entry and press the button, the app crashes. Till then, it works fine. Can someone please help?

The logcat shows the following lines:

```
07-18 00:35:08.628 10497-10497/com.rupiee.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.rupiee.android, PID: 10497
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.rupiee.android.update.UpdateExtrasFragment$1.onClick(UpdateExtrasFragment.java:59)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21168)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

The java code of fragment is as follows:

```
package com.rupiee.android.update;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.rupiee.android.R;
import com.rupiee.android.utils.PreferenceManager;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import static com.rupiee.android.utils.Constants.PREF_APPLICATION_MODE;
import static com.rupiee.android.utils.Constants.PREF_APPMODE_CLIENT;
public class UpdateExtrasFragment extends Fragment {
    private Context mContext;
    public static UpdateExtrasFragment newInstance() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        UpdateExtrasFragment fragment = new UpdateExtrasFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
    protected UpdateExtrasEntryAdapter mUpdateExtrasEntryAdapter;
    @BindView(R.id.list_update_extras_entry) RecyclerView mUpdateExtrasEntryRecyclerView;
    @BindView(R.id.button) Button mButton;
    private PreferenceManager mPreferenceManager;
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mContext = context;
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        @SuppressLint("InflateParams") View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_update_extras, null, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mUpdateExtrasEntryRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mPreferenceManager = PreferenceManager.getInstance(getActivity());
        populateUpdateExtrasEntries();
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int size = mUpdateExtrasEntryAdapter.getItemCount();
                List<String> messlist = new ArrayList<>();
                List<String> amountlist = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    view = mUpdateExtrasEntryRecyclerView.getChildAt(i);
                    EditText mess = view.findViewById(R.id.mess);
                    EditText amount = view.findViewById(R.id.amount);
                    String messname = mess.getText().toString();
                    String amountvalue = amount.getText().toString();
                    messlist.add(messname);
                    amountlist.add(amountvalue);
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, messname+"\n"+amountvalue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
    public void populateUpdateExtrasEntries() {
        if(mUpdateExtrasEntryAdapter == null) {
            mUpdateExtrasEntryAdapter = new UpdateExtrasEntryAdapter(this);
            mUpdateExtrasEntryRecyclerView.setAdapter(mUpdateExtrasEntryAdapter);
        }
        if(PREF_APPMODE_CLIENT.equals(mPreferenceManager.getString(PREF_APPLICATION_MODE))) {
            mUpdateExtrasEntryAdapter.addItem(new UpdateExtrasEntryVo("Mess Card Number", "Amount"), mUpdateExtrasEntryAdapter.getItemCount());
        }
    }
}
```

The XML code of fragment is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Upload All" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list_update_extras_entry"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="true">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share stack trace of logcat when app crashes ?

Comment: 07-18 00:21:28.719 7162-7162/com.rupiee.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.rupiee.android, PID: 7162
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: Can you share code snippet and little bit more stack trace (update in question)? I guess you are facing view not found exception as it may have gone out of screen or  other reasons

Comment: Updated ... Please see if that is sufficient

Answer (score 1):

As per the **logcat** your **view is null** which is returned by `mUpdateExtrasEntryRecyclerView.getChildAt(i);` method in for loop.

You need to review your code with **debugging**, why its getting null for that iteration

Considering scope of question I would suggest **always add null check** [ to avoid runtime NPE ] before performing any operation on view object, as follows

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int size = mUpdateExtrasEntryAdapter.getItemCount();
    List<String> messlist = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> amountlist = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        view = mUpdateExtrasEntryRecyclerView.getChildAt(i);
        if(view != null){
            EditText mess = view.findViewById(R.id.mess);
            EditText amount = view.findViewById(R.id.amount);
            String messname = mess.getText().toString();
            String amountvalue = amount.getText().toString();
            messlist.add(messname);
            amountlist.add(amountvalue);
            Toast.makeText(mContext, messname+"\n"+amountvalue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I sorted out that crash error but one more bug. After some entries, the new entry is coming to the top of recyclerview and if getting the toast of the list, then the item in the one which is at the top does not appear.

Comment: Good reply to a poor question.  @ajinkya bedekar: so exactly how did you resolve the problem?  If somebody else encounters the same issue, it would help them to have an answer.  And if you found this reply helpful, you should "upvote" it, or upvote and accept it.

Comment: instead of using view, I used container. By the way, it's not that you did not face this problem, so it was a poor question. Not everyone is so much intelligent as you and I don't even want to be intelligent if after gaining intelligence, someone gains over-confidence and ego.